# Prevent one data to loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$results = $mysqli->query
("
    SELECT              orders_history.transaction_id,
                        orders_history.items,
                        orders_history.quantity,
                        orders_history.one_product_price,

                        orders_list.status,
                        orders_list.invoices,
                        orders_list.payment_method,
                        orders_list.order_method,


                        delivery_orders.address,
                        delivery_orders.service,
                        delivery_orders.cost,
                        delivery_orders.city

    FROM                orders_history
    LEFT JOIN           orders_list
    ON                  orders_history.transaction_id = orders_list.transaction_id
    LEFT JOIN           infistall_order
    ON                  orders_history.transaction_id = infistall_order.transaction_id
    LEFT JOIN           delivery_orders
    ON                  orders_history.transaction_id = delivery_orders.transaction_id
    WHERE               orders_list.customer_name = 'Klaudia'"      
);

$orders = array();     
$html = '';     
if ($results) {
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $orders[$obj->transaction_id][$obj->items] = array(
            'invoices' => $obj->invoices, 
            'status' => $obj->status, 
            'payment_method' => $obj->payment_method, 
            'service' => $obj->service, 
            'cost' => $obj->cost, 
            'quantity' => $obj->quantity, 
            'one_product_price' => $obj->one_product_price, 
            'city' => $obj->city);
    }

    $html .= '<table width="70%"><tr>';
    $html .= '<td>transaction_id</td>';
    $html .= '<td>items</td>';
    $html .= '<td>quantity</td>';
    $html .= '<td>one_product_price</td>';
    $html .= '<td>status</td>';
    foreach ($orders AS $order_id => $order) {
        $html .= '<tbody><tr><td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $order_id . '</td>';
        $row = 1;
        foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {
            if ($row > 1) { $html .= '</tr><tr>'; }
            $html .= '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['quantity'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['one_product_price'] . '</td>';
            $row++;
            $html .= '<td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $data['status'] . '</td>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr><tbody>';
    }
    $html .= '</table>';
} 
echo $html;
?>
```

The code above will result like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id_cart         products        quantity       invoices     status
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 this               2             $20        
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
  0001           that               1             $20        pending
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
                 those              2             $20                 pending  pending
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 Total Invoices:  $60   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------

                 this               2             $20        
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
  0002           that               1             $20        approved
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
                 those              2             $20                approved   approved
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 Total Invoices:  $60
```

Have a look at the column of status, where the result is looping.

What I want is it shouldn't be looping and only get one result as how the column of id_cart looks like. This is the code for the column of status

```
  $html .= '<td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $data['status'] . '</td>';
```

I need to solve it!

[EDIT]

When I move the code like this:

```
    foreach ($orders AS $order_id => $order) {
        $html .= '<tbody><tr><td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $order_id . '</td>';
        $row = 1;
        foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {
            if ($row > 1) { $html .= '</tr><tr>'; }
            $html .= '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['quantity'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['one_product_price'] . '</td>';
            $row++;
        }
        $html .= '<td rowspan="' . count($order) . '">' . $data['status'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr><tbody>';


 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id_cart         products        quantity       invoices     status
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 this               2             $20        
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
  0001           that               1             $20        
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
                 those              2             $20        pending  
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 Total Invoices:  $60   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                 this               2             $20        
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
  0002           that               1             $20        
                 -------------------------------------------------------    
                 those              2             $20        approved   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 Total Invoices:  $60
```

The resultin the column of status in at the very bottom of the tbody. I want it as how the column of id_cart is.

Comment: Can you echo the html output? I think it's the rowspan.

Comment: Why are You adding `rowspan` to STATUS column? Do You want status information for each products, right?

Comment: @trzEm, No, that not what I want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need 1 value of status per tbody, so put it outside your loop. Also, because you're reusing `$order`, I've put `count($order)` in a seperate variable. Also, close your `</tbody>` tag.

```
foreach ($orders AS $order_id => $order) {
        $orderCount = count($order);
        $html .= '<tbody><tr><td rowspan="' . $orderCount . '">' . $order_id . '</td>';
        $row = 1;
        foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {
            if ($row > 1) { $html .= '</tr><tr>'; }
            $html .= '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['quantity'] . '</td>';
            $html .= '<td>' . $data['one_product_price'] . '</td>';
            if ($row == 1) 
              $html .= '<td rowspan="' . $orderCount . '">' . $data['status'] . '</td>';
            $row++;
        }
          $html .= '</tr></tbody>';
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it, but the status is at the very buttom of the tbody. I want it looks similar to the column of id_card.  Look at my update question.

Comment: I've editted my question with putting `count($order)` in a separate variable.

Comment: it doesn't change anything

Comment: Please echo your `$html` and add it to your question.

Comment: @Klaudia Let us see your css concerning tables too please.

Comment: And you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1zr6q6b1/ right? For all your $orders?

Comment: Close your `</tbody>` tag and apply my solution, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Use valign attribute for td element to get the value aligned center vertically.

```
$html .= '<td rowspan="' . $orderCount . '" valign="middle">' . $data['status'] . '</td>';
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

```
foreach ($order AS $item => $data) {
        if ($row > 1) { $html .= '</tr><tr>'; }
        $html .= '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $data['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $html .= '<td>' . $data['one_product_price'] . '</td>';
        if( $row == 1 ) 
       {
         $html .= '<td style="vertical-align: middle" rowspan="' . count($order) . '">'. $data['status'] . '</td>';
       }
       $row++; 
    }
```

Comment: The vertical align shouldn't be necessary (try it in your jsfiddle). It's also cleaner to put the last row out of the loop.